# How do I submit a jAR with dependencies to Livy?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, livy

I'm using Livy on HDInsight to submit jobs to a Spark cluster. I have my code written and compiled into a JAR, but it has multiple dependencies, some of which are from a custom repository.

How do I get Livy to resolve these dependencies by itself? I dont want to submit a fat jar because the dependencies are changing always and I dont like the ops effort involved.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to pass `spark.jars.ivy` as a parameter. Refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

You can pass anything that Livy supports in the /batches POST body: https://github.com/cloudera/livy#post-batches

Comment: Will this resolve dependencies? i. e. If I mention com.X.Y 0.3, will it also add all the dependencies of com.X.Y mentioned in the pom.xml in the repository?

Comment: It will behave exactly as spark behaves. Try a spark-submit job to figure out which parameters you need to pass, and then replicate with Livy.